# Using Google Maps API to dynamically embed a map based on an address - Need to use Google's data for the markers/bubbles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, embed

I am trying to embed a Google Map into a dynamic webpage. The only variable the map depends on is the address of a business. That address comes from the website's database. I **cannot** just statically generate embed code for each dynamic page using the same set up. Is there a way I can embed a map based on that address and show a marker/bubble showing Google's information on that business?

So far, I have explored a few options including using the Google Map API and the Google Data API or just messing with the embed code given by Google. If I use the APIs it seems I have to design my own types of markers and maybe even supply my own data.

It doesn't look like there is an easy solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm not hung up on going from an address to a longitude and a latitude. I want the info window or "bubble" for a marker to show Google's information of a business.

EDIT: On Roy's suggestion I have been trying to use the map and search API together to achieve what I want. However, the only way I can execute a search with searchControl.execute('business name here'); is if the SearchControl is drawn. Thing is though I don't want to show any search controls. I have been able to hide it, but that just seems like an inefficient hack way of solving this.

Comment: Are you using the Javascript Maps API? The static images one? It sounds like this really shouldn't be too hard. Is your difficulty in generating marker coordinates from the address?

Comment: I am the Javascript Maps API. I want the map to be interactive. My difficulty is not geocoding the address or business name. I just want Google's data to be used for the information "bubble" assigned to the location's map marker.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just use the embed code. Write a bit of Javascript that will draw a map for you and pass it the address.

Loads of examples here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/index.html

I'm not sure which bit you're stuck on, but you don't need to design your own markers. Google can also create a marker from an address and it can find local business information if it has it (using local search API I think).

Comment: Link is 404'ing - updated documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/